# Using a proxy server with Buzz

Tags: php, buzz

**Question:** How can a proxy server be used with [Buzz](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz)?

The commit that added support for proxy can be found [here](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/commit/414def624a630b62ec92c811f17151bcb62f7185). However, it no longer seems to be available in the [latest commit](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Client/AbstractClient.php).

Answer (score 1):

Buzz 0.10 contains basic proxy support (without authentication). `AbstractClient` has a method called `setProxy()` that allows you to specify the address of the proxy server. Example:

```
$client = new FileGetContents();
$client->setProxy('192.168.0.1:8080');
```